# How can i access to multidimensional associative JS array value in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

this is my multidimensional associative javascript array that i have recieved it in PHP:

```
array (size=2)
 0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'count' => string '30' (length=2)
      public 'size' => string '1' (length=0)
      public 'name' => string 'aa' (length=0)
      public 'pid' => string '910' (length=0)
      public 'price' => string '300' (length=0)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'count' => string '30' (length=2)
      public 'size' => string '2' (length=0)
      public 'name' => string 'bb' (length=0)
      public 'pid' => string '920' (length=0)
      public 'price' => string '400' (length=0)
```

How can i access to multidimensional associative JS array value in PHP ?

Comment: Question is answered but I have an additional comment - I assume you used `json_decode()` in your code and got the above result? If so, it's worth noting that `json_decode()` creates `stdClass` object instances for JS object literals by default. However you can enforce PHP associative arrays by passing `true` as the second argument to the `$assoc` argument; e.g: `json_decode($json, true);`. Example here: https://eval.in/132718 - more about `json_decode` here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use it as an object, example

```
foreach($array as $obj) echo $obj->count;
```

Comment: How can i access to `object(stdClass)[1]` or `object(stdClass)[2]` values separately ?

Comment: @Unique `$array[0]->property` or `$array[1]->property`